# get Full Title by id (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

Можно как то получить полный тайтл поста по ID с учетом, что могут быть сео плагины которые изменяют тайтл.

То есть мне нужно то, что выводится в `<title>...</title>` на сингл постах или на страницах.
К примеру на главной выводится "Тайтл сайта - Теглайн"
На страницах - "тайтл страницы - Тайтл сайта"

Вот мне нужен конечный результат, что бы учитывались все хуки\фильтры которые изменяют конечный формат тайтла

Добавлено:

```
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    $wp_query->the_post();

    $id = get_the_id();
    $routes[ $id ] = array(
        ...
        'title' => get_wp_title( $id )
    );
  }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

в коде вырезал все лишнее да бы не путать

Comment: Все SEO плагины учесть невозможно, потому что они могут содержать абсолютно любые ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Полный title поста с учетом всех фильтров в плагинах возвращает `wp_document_title()`.

Проблема в том, что эта функция работает только с текущей страницей. Нижеприведенный код "обманывает" эту функцию, сохраняя текущий запрос wp_query, делая новый основной (это важно!) запрос WordPress с помощью `query_posts()`, сбрасывая результат запроса с помощью `wp_reset_query()` и восстанавливая прежний запрос в глобальной переменной wp_query.

```
function get_wp_title( $id ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $old_wp_query = null;

    $old_wp_query = $wp_query;
    $args         = array(
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'p'         => $id,
    );
    query_posts( $args );
    if ( class_exists( WPSEO_Frontend ) ) {
        WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance()->reset();
    }
    $title = wp_get_document_title();
    wp_reset_query();

    if ( ! empty( $old_wp_query ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $old_wp_query;
        unset( $old_wp_query );
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Использование:

```
echo get_wp_title( $post_id );
```

Код протестирован, работает.

**UPDATE**

При использовании плагина Yoast SEO ситуация существенно усложняется. Этот плагин сам обращается к внутренним глобальным переменным WordPress и кеширует заголовок страницы в private member своего класса. Для того, чтобы обойти кеширование Yoast SEO, в код добавлены следующие строки:

```
if ( class_exists( WPSEO_Frontend ) ) {
    WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance()->reset();
}
```

Сделать сколько-нибудь общий код для **любых плагинов SEO**, как заявлено в вопросе, представляется **невозможным**. Только для Yoast пришлось прибегнуть к глубокому анализу его кода с отладчиком, чтобы добавить всего один вызов функции.

**UPDATE**

Поскольку появились вопросы касательно работоспособности кода, привожу пошаговую инструкцию по созданию тестового примера.

1. На сайте test.kagg.eu создана пустая тестовая страница so733846
2. В папке темы создан файл page-so733846.php

В файл помещен следующий код

```
<?php

// 733846
function get_wp_title( $id ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $old_wp_query = null;

    $old_wp_query = $wp_query;
    $args         = array(
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'p'         => $id,
    );
    query_posts( $args );
    if ( class_exists( WPSEO_Frontend ) ) {
        WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance()->reset();
    }
    $title = wp_get_document_title();
    wp_reset_query();

    if ( ! empty( $old_wp_query ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $old_wp_query;
        unset( $old_wp_query );
    }

    return $title;
}

function so_733846() {
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(
        [
            'post_type'      => 'any',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        ]
    );
    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
            $wp_query->the_post();
            $id = get_the_id();
            echo get_wp_title( $id ) . '<br>';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

so_733846();
```

Результат работы можно увидеть здесь: http://test.kagg.eu/so733846/

Он такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Yoast SEO 5.6.1 стоит, если его вырубить то все ок. Но я искал решение проблемы с учетом, что мы не знаем какой будет сео плагин

Comment: **НЕВОЗМОЖНО** ответить на вопрос для **любых** плагинов. Мне пришлось пару часов полазить по коду Yoast SEO с отладчиком phpStorm + xDebug, чтобы понять, как там что устроено и найти всего один вызов функции, сбрасывающей кеш. Смотрите обновленный ответ.

Comment: И потом - что это за задача такая-то на сайт вы воткнуть можете, а какой там плагин стоит - не знаете

Comment: я просто думал, что есть решение, которое выдает конечный вариант тайтла

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67707/discussion-on-answer-by-kagg-design-get-full-title-by-id-wordpress).